# Angular 5 production build errors out on inherited properties marked as Protected in Typescript - 'property does not exist on type' *Component

Tags: typescript, angular5, ng-build

Angular 5.2.8
Typescript 2.6.1
CLI 1.6.8

My app generates build files if run in normal development mode using ng serve. However, when I run `ng build --prod I get below errors

```
Property 'status' is protected and only accessible within class 'ModuleBaseComponent' and its subclasses
```

But property 'status' is a field declared in ModuleBaseComponent. Its resolved if changed from protected to public but whats the use of protected keyword then!

```
export class ModuleBaseComponent {
protected status = 'inactive';
...
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-themeA-preferences',
  templateUrl: './../common/my-common-theme.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-themeA.component.scss']
})
export class MyThemeAComponent extends ModuleBaseComponent implements OnInit {}
```

Common html must rely on the component where-ever this particular html is referred via templateUrl in the decorator. Then inheritance has to figure-out the variables used in the html.

Please can someone advise on above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Properties that you use in your templates **MUST** be public when compiling in AOT mode.

[Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler):

> The compiler can only reference exported symbols.
>
> Decorated component class members must be public. You cannot make an @Input() property private or internal.
>
> Data bound properties must also be public.